# How to replace multi if/else statement if condition is a method with different params

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring, conditional-statements

I found answers where the condition was the same field e.g. if `a==1` if `a==2` etc. where I can easily change it to `switch`, but what in the case like below?

But what if the condition is a method (same method and difference is only in one parameter)

This is an example:

```
public float doSomething(Object object) throws invalidObjectException {
    float numberToReturn = 0f;

    if (isTypeValid(messages.getString("param1"), object.getType())) {
        //do something e.g.
        numberToReturn += Integer.parseInt(object.getTime()) * 1;
    } else if (isTypeValid(messages.getString("param2"), object.getType())) {
        //do something else e.g.
        numberToReturn += Float.parseFloat(object.getTime()) * 2;
    } else if (isTypeValid(messages.getString("param3"), object.getType())) {
        //do something else e.g.
        numberToReturn += Integer.parseInt(object.getTime()) * 3;

    } else {
        //do something else e.g.
        throw new invalidObjectException("Type " + object.getType() + " is invalid.");
    }
    return numberToReturn;
}
```

Like you can notice I have nearly same if conditions (difference is in a first param) and

Any ideas how to make it more readable for other programmers?

I think it is not really important, but this is how my isTpeValid looks like.

```
public boolean isTypeValid(String validTypes, String actualType) {
    String[] split = validTypes.split("\\s+");
    return Arrays.asList(split).contains(actualType) ? true : false;
}
```

messages.getString("param2") is a part of i18n (internatialization), where we have

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("file_name", locale);
```

In a file_name_en I have example data with valid types for english:

```
param1=a b c
param2=d e
param3=f
```

In a file_name_de I have example data with valid types for german:

```
param1=g h
param2=i j k 
param3=l
```

So as example upper says:

```
if object.getType is valid with param1:
    //do something
if object.getType is valid with param2:
    //do something else etc.
```

Comment: Are the "something else" that you want to do similar to each other?

Comment: Maybe using a for loop and inside it a switch and the method? I'm not really sure what do you want

Comment: Why not use `switch` based on the  `param3` passed in `isTypeValid()` method?

Comment: @Sweeper they are similar, but not exacly the same (I printed this something else also so you can see what its doing in example)

Comment: @AlexCuadrón I try to make this code more readable. I'll try this.

Comment: @VPK I do not get how you can do a switch based on the param3? What with param2 and param1? Can you print an example as an answeR?

Comment: @degath, that was just an example mate! Post your `isTypeValid()` method so that we can look into it.

Comment: @VPK added isTypeValid to a question.and also added example data.

Comment: @degath please describe your   messages.getString("param1")  . What is messages exactly?

Comment: @WalterKuhn they are part of i18n (internationalization). So e.g. param1 is a key for a value inside properties file (depending on locale it is changed to read from another proprties file). So messages is: ResourceBundlemessages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("file_name", locale_name);

Comment: Maybe it's fine to let it stay like now? What do you think? Is it even readable for you?

Comment: What's `Object.getType()`?

Comment: You could replace the code with a map of `BiPredicate`/`Function`. But I doubt this would make the code more readable for just three rules. If you have much more then it might make sense.

Comment: Also your predicates and functions seem pretty similar. Can't you just iterate over all the `paramN`s?

Comment: @lexicore it's a String "a" or "b" or "c" etc. And, if it's inside param1 or param2 or param3, will do something. depending on the type we will do the multiplication  so e.g. if object.getType() is inside param1 multiply by 1, if object.getType() is inside param2 multiply by 2  etc.

Comment: @lexicore Yeah, I have only 3 of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166379/discussion-between-degath-and-lexicore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a working example of the following code on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CuddlyDelightfulOpensource)

## Code

You can replace the `if-else` by creating a lookup table that uses the type as a key and a function as the value.

```
Map<String, BiFunction<String, Float, Float>> typeFunctionLookup = new HashMap<>();
typeFunctionLookup.put("a", (time, x) -> x + Integer.parseInt(time) * 1);
typeFunctionLookup.put("b", (time, x) -> x + Float.parseFloat(time) * 2);
typeFunctionLookup.put("c", (time, x) -> x + Integer.parseInt(time) * 3);
```

After that we have to find a type within this lookup value. This could be done with:

```
public static Optional<Entry<String, BiFunction<String, Float, Float>>> findEntry(String type, Map<String, BiFunction<String, Float, Float>> types) {
    return types.entrySet().stream()
          .filter(x -> isTypeValid(x.getKey(), type))
          .findFirst();
}
```

`findEntry` returns an `Optional`. And if this option exists, we want to perform the function stored by the map. Otherwise we will just return the value without changing it by a function.

```
public static float handeType(Optional<Entry<String, BiFunction<String, Float, Float>>> type, String time, float value) {
    return type.isPresent() 
        ? type.get().getValue().apply(time, value)
        : value;
}
```

Now we can call `handeType(findEntry(TYPE, typeFunctionLookup), OBJECT_TIME, OBJECT_TYPE)`